# c# extension method for a generic class with interface as type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, interface, extension-methods

Is it possible in c# - and if so how - to extend a generic class but only if the generic type parameter implements a special interface?

For example something like this:

```
public static void SomeMethod(
    this SomeClass<ISomeInterface> obj, ISomeInterface objParam)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: sure, an extension method is just syntactic sugar for a static method that accepts something. That something can be everything of course. Just try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by making the method generic and adding a generic type constraint to the method, as follows:

```cs
public static void SomeMethod<T>(
    this SomeClass<T> obj, ISomeInterface objParam)
    where T : ISomeInterface // <-- generic type constraint
{
    ...
}
```